# Taking picture of ID card and pulling the text using tesseract library

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

I'm creating an app that scans an ID card and pulls the text and stores it. I have it to the point where I can upload an image, but how would I go about taking a picture from the app?

Comment: you can take a picture with a camera. `AVFoundation` is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the Subclasses UIIMagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate

after that call the non-optional delegate methods and implement them :)

```
let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()

pickerController.delegate = self

pickerController.allowsEditing = true


pickerController.sourceType = .camera
present(pickerController, animated: true)
```